# Angular 2 url with queryParam after reload

Tags: angular

I have a few urls with `queryParams`. And i'm stuck with problem: after page reload inside url appears slash. Why this happening?

> ```
> http://localhost:8000/photos?user_id=1
> http://localhost:8000/photos/?user_id=1
> ```

In routes:

```
{ path: 'photos', component : PhotosComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```

In anchor tag:

```
[routerLink]="['/photos']" [queryParams]="{user_id: _userId}"
```

Comment: What are you using in server end?

Comment: in backend Django REST

Comment: Django automatically changes the url and appends `/`. So create all your url's with `/` appended

Comment: Thank you, but i can't figure out where i can set this. Cause angular2 automatically doesn't append slash to `urls`.

Comment: Do the same thing in your angular2 routes.
`{ path: 'photos/', component : PhotosComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }`
This should not be a problem, I guess

Comment: but i can't navigate to url with this path.